# RestSharp OAuth1Authenticator GET params omitted from signature base string

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth, restsharp

I'm trying to write an OAuth 1 REST client using RestSharp, and I'm running into some invalid signature problems with GET requests. I stepped through the code, and it seems the problem is that, for GET requests, the request parameters are omitted from the signature base string. In particular, the offending code in OAuth1Authenticator.cs is this:

```
// for non-GET style requests make sure params are part of oauth signature
if (request.Method != Method.GET && request.Method != Method.DELETE)
{
    foreach (var p in request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type == ParameterType.GetOrPost))
    {
        parameters.Add(new WebPair(p.Name, p.Value.ToString()));
    }
}
```

If I remove the if statement, it works as expected.

Am I misunderstanding something? Based on the signature base string example in the OAuth spec here: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#sig_base_example, it looks like it should be adding these parameters to the base signature. Is this a bug in the OAuth1Authenticator, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure. Can you post this to the google group where there are more people that can help? http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp

Comment: Thanks John! I did yesterday, but no answers yet.